# Inno Setup : Stack Overflow or Super User?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, superuser, scope

Inno Setup is used to create installation packages using a script. If I have a question on Inno Setup, should I go to Stack Overflow or Super User?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it's better suited to Stack Overflow.  Super User is for end-users and computer enthusiasts; some scripting questions are appropriate, but if you're packaging a development project it seems a little outside of SU's scope.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say if it is asking how to code the script, then it's StackOverflow.

However, if it's how to workaround or otherwise install an existing package (i.e. it doesn't involve recompiling the installation package) it's SuperUser.